# Swing integrado com JavaFX é possível?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jbutton

Queria saber se é possível chamar uma tela JavaFX através de um Botão de uma tela Swing.
O código da tela JavaFX que quero chamar é o seguinte:

```
public class EditorHTML extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Crie o HTMLEditor
        HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
        // Definir a altura do HTMLEditor
        htmlEditor.setPrefHeight(300);
        // Definir a largura do HTMLEditor
        htmlEditor.setPrefWidth(600);

        // Crie a cena
        Scene scene = new Scene(htmlEditor);
        // Adicione a cena ao palco
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // Definir o título do palco
        stage.setTitle("HTMLEditor Exemplo");


        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Acredito q nao. Apesar do JavaFX permitir a inserção e uso de componentes swing dentro de uma aplicação feita nessa API, no caso do swing, não é mais atualizado, portanto, não foi feita essa compatibilidade.

Comment: Bom, eu consegui chamar uma 'tela' em JavaFX através do FXML, mas não consigo fazer o mesmo com essa Tela do HTMLEditor, por que ela não possui FXML, mesmo sendo do tipo JavaFX, gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de gerar um código FXML a partir dessa classe .Java pra que eu possa chamar através dele.